# Kotlin: override generic property within subtype

Tags: generics, overriding, kotlin

I trying to write some generic code, but can't get rid of `Type of 'PROPERTY' is not a subtype of the overridden property` error.

Simplified version of my code:

```
abstract class BaseP<V> {
    var view: V? = null
}

abstract class BaseF {
    fun smth() {
        pp.view = this
    }
    abstract val pp: BaseP<BaseF>
}

abstract class SubF: BaseF() {
    abstract override val pp: BaseP<SubF>
    // Error:(20, 30) Type of 'pp' is not a subtype of the overridden property 'public abstract val pp: BaseP<BaseF> defined in BaseF'
}
```

I found that error can be `@Suppress`-ed, but I doubt it is best and only way. Is there something better?

And after all I can't understand, why `subtypeA<subtypeB>` doesn't count as subtype of `baseA<baseB>`, can someone explain this?

Comment: what line throws the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `SubtypeA<B>` is a subtype of `BaseA<B>`, so the problem is in the generics parameters subtyping.

The answer lies in [Kotlin generics variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), which is similar to [that of Java](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance).

> Why doesn't `SubtypeA<SubtypeB>` count as subtype of `BaseA<BaseB>`?

The generics are invariant by default, which means that, even in simpler case, for a class `A<T>`, `A<SubtypeB>` and `A<BaseB>` are not subtypes of each other unless otherwise is specified by variance modifiers `in` and `out` (or [Java wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)).

Two cases are possible:

- If you want only to *take* `T` instances out of instances of your class `A`, then you can use `out` modifier: `A<out T>`.

  Here `A<SubtypeB>` becomes a subtype of `A<BaseB>`, because from `A<SubtypeB>` you can obviously take instances of `BaseB`, and not vice versa.
- If you want only to *pass* `T` into your class' methods, then use `in` modifier in your class declaration: `A<in T>`.

  And here `A<BaseB>` is a subtype of `A<SubtypeB>`, because every instance of `A<BaseB>` can also receive `SubtypeB` into the methods, but not vice versa.

If you both pass and take `T` to/from your class `A<T>`, then the only option for `T` it is to be invariant, so that neither `A<SubB>` nor `A<SuperB>` are subtypes of `A<B>`: otherwise would lead to a contradiction to the above.

And this is exactly the case: in your `BaseP<B>`, you are both taking items of `V` and putting ones into `view` property, so `V` can only be invariant, and `BaseP<SubF>` is not a subtype of `BaseP<BaseF>`, neither is `SubP<SubF>`.