# Kotlin generics super/child classes

Tags: generics, kotlin

Trying to use generic types classes but got following problem, which is:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is `ChildClass` but `SuperClass<SuperType>` was expected

```
open class SuperClass<T> where T: SuperType {
    fun modifySomething(input: T): T {
        input.someValue.inc()
        return input
    }
}

open class SuperType {
    val someValue: Int = 0
}

class ChildClass : SuperClass<ChildType>() 

class ChildType: SuperType() {
    fun getModifiedValue(): Int {
        return someValue
    }
}

class TestEnvironment {
    fun testType(superClass: SuperClass<SuperType>) { 
        // do something with superClass
    }

    fun itDoesntWork() {
        testType(ChildClass()) // compilation error
    }
}
```

Here is [the gist](https://gist.github.com/TGIO/53482514ccba395646ba4deda7df6452) and [the kotlin playground](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/45k09ue3l8ccr530tgtj8an59/9t1q74hrftmgm2jivua9omd15i)

**Desired result is that function** `testType(superClass: SuperClass<SuperType>)` **should accept class** `ChildClass()` **without using `*` wildcard**

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [generics variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) that prevents your code from working. `SuperClass` is defined as

```
open class SuperClass<T> where T: SuperType { ... }
```

And its type parameter `T` is declared as invariant (it has no `out` or `in` modifiers). Therefore the subtyping relations are as follows:

- `DerivedClass<ChildType>` is **not** a subtype of `SuperClass<SuperType>`
- `SuperClass<ChildType>` is **not** a subtype of `SuperClass<SuperType>`
- `DerivedClass<SuperType>` **is** a subtype of `SuperClass<SuperType>`.

Since the function argument should belong to a subtype of the parameter type, and `ChildClass` is actually `DerivedClass<ChildType>`, you cannot pass `ChildClass` as a `SuperClass<SuperType>`.

You can solve this problem by adding the [`out` projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) to the parameter type of `testType`:

```
fun testType(superClass: SuperClass<out SuperType>)
```

This will basically mean that this function accepts `SuperClass<T>` where `T` is a subtype of `SuperType`. Of course, it adds certain limitations on the `superClass` usage: as `T` can be absolutely any subtype of `SuperType`, it is not type-safe to pass anything to functions that expect `T` as an argument, and this is prohibited.

Also, see another answer that explains the reason for the invariant generics behavior: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431249/kotlin-override-generic-property-within-subtype)